# "Telephone" is a required value in customer edit form

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have overrided customer edit form. But while saving record I'm getting error message

> "Telephone" is a required value.

I don't want telephone field. So in my form telephone field is not there but still error is coming.

Comment: Now try this Store -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration Tab -> Name and Address Options -> Show Telephone Required just set No and save it.

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala but there is no Telephone field under Customer Configuration  tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Magento2 feature that is by default telephone field is required.
    There is a lot of discussion on below topic:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1691

There is also a suggestion on this topic that we can make it optional by running SQL script

```
update eav_attribute set is_required=0 where attribute_code='telephone';
```

Read full topic and then run the query.

**Note:** Take a backup of DB before making any change.

After run query check `eav_attribute` table and make sure attribute column value changed to `is_required` to `0`.[image]

Run reindex command for attributes only

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

and delete all cache and static files, compile and regenerate code by below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have done all changes but getting same error

Comment: did you reindex?since you have changed attribute hence you will require fully reindex and then clear all cache.

Comment: Now I have done reindexing. But still same issue exist

Comment: I have put hidden value <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone"  value="999999999"> . But still does not work

Comment: update answer check it and try to fully delete all cache and reindex.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove telephone field from using following changes.

- Using sql query `update eav_attribute set is_required=0 where attribute_code='telephone';`
- Modified
  Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Validator::validateForCustomer()
- Modified Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel
  \AddressRepository::_validate()
- Modified Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress::validate()

Comment: I have done all changes but getting same error

Comment: please try with clear cache, and regenerate static content.

Comment: I have put hidden value <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone"  value="999999999"> . But still does not work

Comment: @AasimGoriya what specifically did you modify in those classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in the answer by akgola, except instead of following the step:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

I instead ran

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

and this worked for me. It is a customer and not product attribute being updated, so that is probably why that answer isn't working for others?